# Select values with max date for each ID

Tags: c#, linq

This is the table "history"

```
id  value   date
1   1   01/01/2017 20:20:20
1   2   02/01/2017 20:20:20
1   3   03/01/2017 20:20:20
2   5   01/01/2017 20:20:20
2   6   02/01/2017 20:20:20
```

How with linq select max values for each id

```cs
context.History
    .GroupBy(x => x.id) ??
    .SelectOnlyWithMax(z => z.date) ??
```

In result only two objects

```
id  value   date
1   3   03/01/2017 20:20:20
2   6   02/01/2017 20:20:20
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried, maybe start with `GroupBy`...

Comment: What result do you want, `Id`, `Value`, or the entire row with the highest date?

Comment: Also, do you need this for Entity Framework?  If so, it could restrict some of the possible answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want the entire row with the highest date for each `Id`, you can use the following code (written with LinqPad).  If you just want the `Id`, you can use @BurnsBA's answer, as it will be slightly more efficient.

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<Record>
    {
        new Record(){Id=1, Value=1, Date=new DateTime(2017,1,1)},
        new Record(){Id=1, Value=2, Date=new DateTime(2017,2,1)},
        new Record(){Id=1, Value=3, Date=new DateTime(2017,3,1)},
        new Record(){Id=2, Value=5, Date=new DateTime(2017,1,1)},
        new Record(){Id=2, Value=6, Date=new DateTime(2017,2,1)},
    };


    var query = data.GroupBy(d => d.Id)
                    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date)
                                      .Take(1));
    query.Dump();
}

public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Results:

[image]

First it groups by `Id`, then sorts the items within the group by `Date` in descending order, and returns the first one, `SelectMany` then flattens the list.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
public class History
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

// setup:
var values = new List<History>();
values.Add(new History() { id = 1, value = 1, date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017 20:20:20") });
values.Add(new History() { id = 1, value = 2, date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017 20:20:20") });
values.Add(new History() { id = 1, value = 3, date = DateTime.Parse("03/01/2017 20:20:20") });
values.Add(new History() { id = 2, value = 5, date = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2017 20:20:20") });
values.Add(new History() { id = 2, value = 6, date = DateTime.Parse("02/01/2017 20:20:20") });

// result :
values.GroupBy(
    x => x.id, 
    y => y.date,
    // Below, dates will be enumerable
    (id, dates) => new { id = id, date = dates.Max() }
)

// returns enumerable collection of anonymous type:
{
    { id = 1, date = [3/1/2017 8:20:20 PM] }, 
    { id = 2, date = [2/1/2017 8:20:20 PM] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s `MaxBy` function, that is:

```
context.History.GroupBy( x => x.id ).Select( x => x.MaxBy( y => y.date) )
```

Comment: Is this Entity Framework compatible?  The question wasn't tagged with EF, but from the way they are querying through a variable named `context`, and the fact that they mention "tables", makes me think that they need  something that supports Entity Framework.  Based on a quick scan of the source for `MaxBy`, it may not be.