# Entity Get latest results based on date

Tags: c#, sql, entity

I have the following table:

```
------------------------------------
userid | testid | date     | result
1      | 1      | 18-01-01 | 1
1      | 1      | 18-01-09 | 6
1      | 3      | 18-01-09 | 5
1      | 3      | 18-01-10 | 2
```

Now i need to get 2 rows using Entity: The following:

```
------------------------------------
userid | testid | date     | result
1      | 1      | 18-01-09 | 6
1      | 3      | 18-01-10 | 2
```

I need a LINQ query that returns the latest result of each testid in the database. The userID/testID is the group. What is the best and fastest way to get this information?

Thanks,

Comment: Group by ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query?

Comment: related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939168/select-values-with-max-date-for-each-id?noredirect=1&lq=1 at least 5 exact dupe.

Comment: thanks, could not find it. I used other search words.

Answer (score 2):

Just `GroupBy()` the `testid` and select the latest of each group

```
var result = ctx.Items.GroupBy(x => x.testid)
                      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.date).First());
```